# Kivy ScreenManager and BoxLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm just in the learning process of Kivy and have made a simple example. There should be 2 screens. Every screen should have a menu bar. The menu bars are shown at the bottom of the 2 screens. This works perfectly. Now I try to put the menu bar at the top of the screens and don't get my example running.

Here is the snippet of my code that works:

```
<ScreenOverview>:
    name:   "ScreenOverview"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: 'Overview Screen'
            font_size: 50

        MenuBar:
```

When I switch the MenuBar with Button, I only see the Button at the bottom:

```
<ScreenOverview>:
    name:   "ScreenOverview"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MenuBar:

        Button:
            text: 'Overview Screen'
            font_size: 50
```

Only using the MenuBar, I can see the MenuBar, but also at the bottom and not at the top.

```
<ScreenOverview>:
    name:   "ScreenOverview"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MenuBar:
```

I search here and tried many hints and examples, but I don't get my code to work. Can anybody explain my mistalke?

Here is my complete py-code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class MenuBar( Button ):
    pass

class ScreenOverview( Screen ):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( ScreenOverview, self ).__init__( **kwargs )

    def switchToScreen( self ):
        if( self.manager.current == "ScreenBookings" ):
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition( direction="left" )
            self.manager.current = "ScreenOverview"

class ScreenBookings( Screen ):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( ScreenBookings, self ).__init__( **kwargs )

    def switchToScreen( self ):
        if( self.manager.current == "ScreenOverview" ):
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition( direction="right" )
            self.manager.current = "ScreenBookings"

class RVScreenManager( ScreenManager ):
    pass

class RVApp( App ):
    def build( self ):
        self.ScreenManager = RVScreenManager()

        self.ScreenOverview = ScreenOverview( name="ScreenOverview")
        self.ScreenManager.add_widget( self.ScreenOverview )

        self.ScreenBookings = ScreenBookings( name="ScreenBookings")
        self.ScreenManager.add_widget( self.ScreenBookings )

        return( self.ScreenManager )

    def switchScreenOverview( self ):
        self.ScreenOverview.switchToScreen()

    def switchScreenBookings( self ):
        self.ScreenBookings.switchToScreen()

Builder.load_file( "sf-fragen01.kv" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RVApp().run()
```

And the kv file:

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<RVScreenManager>:
    id: ScreenManager

    ScreenOverview:
        name: "ScreenOverview"
        screen_manager: "ScreenManager"
    ScreenBookings:
        name: "ScreenBookings"
        screen_manager: "ScreenManager"

<ScreenOverview>:
    name:   "ScreenOverview"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: 'Overview Screen'
            font_size: 50

        MenuBar:

<ScreenBookings>:
    name: "ScreenBookings"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: 'Bookings Screen'
            font_size: 50

        MenuBar:

<MenuButton@Button>:
    font_size:      20
    text_size:      self.size
    halign:         "center"
    valign:         "center"

<MenuBar>:
    name: "MenuBar"

    BoxLayout:
        size:       root.size[0], root.size[1]

        MenuButton:
            on_release:
                app.switchScreenOverview()
            text: 'Overview'

        MenuButton:
            on_release:
                app.switchScreenBookings()
            text: 'Bookings'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be due to your `MenuBar` extending `Button`. It make more sense for `MenuBar` to extend some type of `Layout`. Here is your py code with the `MenuBar` extending `BoxLayout`:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class MenuBar( BoxLayout ):
    pass

class ScreenOverview( Screen ):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( ScreenOverview, self ).__init__( **kwargs )

    def switchToScreen( self ):
        if( self.manager.current == "ScreenBookings" ):
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition( direction="left" )
            self.manager.current = "ScreenOverview"

class ScreenBookings( Screen ):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super( ScreenBookings, self ).__init__( **kwargs )

    def switchToScreen( self ):
        if( self.manager.current == "ScreenOverview" ):
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition( direction="right" )
            self.manager.current = "ScreenBookings"

class RVScreenManager( ScreenManager ):
    pass

class RVApp( App ):
    def build( self ):
        self.ScreenManager = RVScreenManager()

        self.ScreenOverview = ScreenOverview( name="ScreenOverview")
        self.ScreenManager.add_widget( self.ScreenOverview )

        self.ScreenBookings = ScreenBookings( name="ScreenBookings")
        self.ScreenManager.add_widget( self.ScreenBookings )

        return( self.ScreenManager )

    def switchScreenOverview( self ):
        self.ScreenOverview.switchToScreen()

    def switchScreenBookings( self ):
        self.ScreenBookings.switchToScreen()

Builder.load_file( "sf-fragen01.kv" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RVApp().run()
```

And the `.kv` file with the `MenuBar` at the top. Note that the `MenuBar` no longer contains a `BoxLayout`, because `MenuBar` is a `BoxLayout`:

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<RVScreenManager>:
    id: ScreenManager

    ScreenOverview:
        name: "ScreenOverview"
        screen_manager: "ScreenManager"
    ScreenBookings:
        name: "ScreenBookings"
        screen_manager: "ScreenManager"

<ScreenOverview>:
    name:   "ScreenOverview"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MenuBar:

        Button:
            text: 'Overview Screen'
            font_size: 50

<ScreenBookings>:
    name: "ScreenBookings"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MenuBar:

        Button:
            text: 'Bookings Screen'
            font_size: 50

<MenuButton@Button>:
    font_size:      20
    text_size:      self.size
    halign:         "center"
    valign:         "center"

<MenuBar>:
    name: "MenuBar"

    size:       root.size[0], root.size[1]

    MenuButton:
        on_release:
            app.switchScreenOverview()
        text: 'Overview'

    MenuButton:
        on_release:
            app.switchScreenBookings()
        text: 'Bookings'
```

Comment: That was the problem and it works now! Thank you very much.